# Android BLE Disconnecting after multiple devices connect

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working with android BLE. in this task android application should connect to multiple BLE devices and it's ok. I can connect successfully.

I know this code is need to connecting BLE device:

```
BluetoothGatt gaat = device.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, gattCallback);
```

I using `Map<String, BluetoothGatt> connectedDeviceMap` to keep BLE devices `addresses` and `BluetoothGatt`:

```
    List<BluetoothDevice> devices = bluetoothManager.getConnectedDevices(BluetoothProfile.GATT);
    if (devices != null && !(devices.isEmpty())) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
            if (device.getType() == BluetoothDevice.DEVICE_TYPE_LE) {
                BluetoothDevice d = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(device.getAddress());
                gatt = d.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, gattCallback);
                connectedDeviceMap.put(d.getAddress(), gatt);
            }
        }
    }
```

as you can see for getting gatt value for each device I need to call  `connectGatt` function. but when this function call multiple times, devices disconnecting from the application (i think this is because fulling memory of BLE)

so i using `close()` to release all memory and connect again :

```
 List<BluetoothDevice> devices = bluetoothManager.getConnectedDevices(BluetoothProfile.GATT);
if (devices != null && !(devices.isEmpty())) {
    for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
        if (device.getType() == BluetoothDevice.DEVICE_TYPE_LE) {
            BluetoothDevice d = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(device.getAddress());
            gatt = d.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, gattCallback);
            connectedDeviceMap.put(d.getAddress(), gatt);
            gatt .close();
        }
    }
}
```

but this not working and also devices disconecting from application when calling multiple times `connectGatt`.

Answer (score 0):

Like in this example [Android BLE multiple connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47404018/android-ble-multiple-connections).
If I see correctly diff between your solution and this in link, is you don't check device connection state

Comment: I checked device connection state in another code. but problem still not sloved

Comment: you check before connection and before close?

Comment: yes, I checked before connection if connected before ignoring and after that if closed before ignore and continue